# Is it possible to arrange listview items as tiles in android

Tags: android, android-listview

Is it possible to arrange listview items as tiles in android.  Please see below picture.

[image]

Comment: use gridview instead of listview

Comment: dude android have GridView to achieve this. use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Yes it is possible.

Use [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) to shows items in two-dimensional scrolling grid.  It uses the same [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html)  inside.

Refer [Android GridView Layout Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/)

and

[Grid View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) example in developer docs

Comment: May i insert an item with image and text in gridview

Comment: Yes you can do that too.. See http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-custom-grid-view-example-with-image-and-text.html